# Derivative of convolution with singular kernel

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convolution, singular-integrals

Define for $f:[0,b]\to\mathbb R$
$$
F(t):=\int_0^tf(t-s)s^{-\gamma}\,ds,\quad \gamma\in(0,1).
$$
(i) Does a continuous $f$ exists so that $F$ not differentiable on $(0,b)$?

(ii) Does a continuous $f$ exists so that $F'$ exists on $(0,b)$ but it is not integrable?